# MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 232

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have the following Bus model:

```
class Bus extends Model
{
    protected $guarded =[''];
    protected $fillable = ['plate_num','seat_num'];

    public function seats(){

        return $this->hasMany(Seat::class);
    }

    public function addSeat($number){

        $this->seats()->create([
            'seat_num'=> $number

            ]);
    }
}
```

And in my BusController I have the following store function that gets 2 values from a form('plate_num' and 'seats_num')

Although I have the **$fillable** array with the fields needed(**Seat@seat_num** and **Bus@plate_num**), however,  Whenever I submit the form I get the following error:

> MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 232 Seat_num

The logic of the code is basically whenever i key in the **bus plate number** and **number of seats** for example **"ABC213"** and **"5"**, one record should be created in the buses table that includes the plate_num, and 5 records should b created in the Seats table whereby each record gets the id of the bus and the seat number.

Comment: Is the 'seat_num' attribute on your Bus or Seat model? The way you're creating the seat in the `addSeat()` method makes me think it's on your `Seat` model, which means that's where you need to add it as a `fillable` attr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

edit your model

```
protected $fillable = ['plate_num'];
```

add in your seat model

```
protected $fillable = ['seat_num'];
```

now you can use in your controller to add

```
use App\seat;
use App\bus;
public function add(){
$seat = new seat;
$bus = new bus;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to fill in `$fillable` array in `Seat` model and not in `Bus` model.

When using:

```
$this->seats()->create(...);
```

you create `Seat` models so in this case fillable is used from `Seat` model.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line in your model.

```
protected $guarded =[''];
```

You should only set guarded or fillable and not both. Also check if you've set the correct fillable properties in the related models. Posting more code of what you're trying to do will help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix [Laravel MassAssignmentException in model.php](http://guruquest.net/question/laravel-massassignmentexception-in-model-php-in-php/) need to follow below steps:

It can occur due to two possibilities:

For a mass assignment,  need to provide all the fields of a model which will be mass assigned while during an update or create operation.

```
protected $fillable = ['age', 'phone', 'mail', 'location', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Table name should  be assigned in $table = “user_info” in model file